# Preciso implementar um serviço de push notifications em react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Estou trabalhando em um app para médicos, neste aplicativo eu preciso notificar ao usuário quando a hora do agendamento for igual a do celular.

Duvidas e problemas

- Como fazer uma função que compara a hora atual com a hora do agendamento vinda da API, com o aplicativo fechado, em segundo plano, ativo e sendo assim, notificar ao usuário

aceito dicas de como fazer isso de um jeito mais facil

Posso disponibilizar o código, nao coloquei aqui porque eu nao consigo desenvolver essa parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito interessante seu problema, e acho que você pode resolver isso agendando as notificações, para isso tente usar a biblioteca [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

Mais especificamente nesse [ponto](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#scheduled-notifications), onde são especificadas essas notificações agendadas.

Uma terceira questão é como o dado do agendamento chegaria até seu dispositivo, para isso eu usaria uma estratégia de **SSE** (server sent events), onde o *client* é quem ouve eventos disparados pelo seu *backend*. E aqui você pode encontrar um ferramenta para isso: [SSE](https://github.com/jordanbyron/react-native-event-source).

Logo o fluxo ficaria basicamente assim:

Um agendamento é feito -> O evento de agendamento é disparado -> a informação do evento chega no seu dispositivo -> uma nova notificação é agendada

Mas lembre-se: o *listener* de eventos vindos do backend tem que funcionar em background e para isso existem várias soluções, uma que gosto muito é a [react-native-background-actions](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions), vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Não conheço a tecnologia mas a ideia está certinha, esse tipo de processamento tem que ser feito do lado do servidor e informado via _push notification_ para o app móvel, a plataforma móvel geralmente dá suporte para o comportamento de acordar e notificar apps que estejam dormentes ou desligadas por razão de economia de recursos. +1

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado!